# Certificates for API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobilepush

We have implemented a Mobile Push application. Now we are in need of certificate which is used by ExactTarget API (all the CA certificates that Exact Target SDK use in DER Encoded Binary X.509 (.cer) format.))

Is there any documentation for this certificate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download the certificates, I did the following

1. Open Firefox and access the URL link: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
2. Just adjacent to the link in the address bar, there is a lock icon. Click on that and then click on exacttargetAPIs.com and finally click on "More information"
3. Click on "View certificate"
4. Click on "Details" tab and then click on export.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what artifacts you are requesting.  If you registered an app with our AppCenter for SFMC MobilePush then you would have provided a certificate to us for APNS and/or GCM sending.

Comment: Apologies I did not explain it clearly. We need to do Certificate Pinning in our Mobile Application for Security reasons. We have pinned all the certificates that our application use. We need to have similar certificates of Exact Target API’s too that we can pin in the application for smoothly using Exact Target SDK.
 
This means we need all the CA certificates that Exact Target SDK use in DER Encoded Binary X.509 (.cer) format. Thanks